# Mixed model with lme4 failed to converge with max|grad|

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4

When I ran the model lme4, I got this error message but could still get the summary. My dataset is as follows: categorical response is object_case(binary: nominative (marked as 1) and partitive (0)); random effect factor is verb_lemma; the explanatory variables are number(singular or plural), animacy(animate, inanimate or person), order (VO or OV), tense (present or past), resultativity (yes or no) and boundedness (yes or no).[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vECwO.png)
My code is as follows:

```
m2 = glmer(object_case ~ number + animacy + order + tense + resultativity + 
             boundedness + (1|verb_lemma), data = my_dataset, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

However, I got the warning like

```
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.26418 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

But I can still get the summary

```
> summary(m2)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: object_case ~ Arv + Elusus + Järjekord + Aeg + piiritletus_s +      piiritletus_o + (1 | verb_lemma)
   Data: lra

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   148.7    183.3    -65.4    130.7      336 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.71743 -0.00001  0.00004  0.00723  0.75621 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 verb_lemma (Intercept) 218.5    14.78   
Number of obs: 345, groups:  verb_lemma, 171

Fixed effects:
                           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                 -16.411      8.946  -1.834   0.0666 .  
ArvMitmus                    -1.223      1.405  -0.871   0.3839    
ElususEluta                  -9.782      7.993  -1.224   0.2210    
ElususInimene               -12.344      8.615  -1.433   0.1519    
JärjekordVO                  -1.281      1.853  -0.691   0.4893    
AegOlevik                    -0.375      1.530  -0.245   0.8064    
piiritletus_sPiiritlematud   21.882      5.074   4.312 1.61e-05 ***
piiritletus_oPiiritlematud   15.440      2.768   5.577 2.44e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) ArvMtm ElssEl ElssIn JrjkVO AgOlvk prtlts_sP
ArvMitmus   -0.210                                             
ElususEluta -0.760  0.227                                      
ElususInimn -0.735  0.188  0.979                               
JärjekordVO -0.402  0.154  0.441  0.436                        
AegOlevik   -0.380 -0.119  0.272  0.295  0.070                 
prtlts_sPrt -0.307 -0.160 -0.324 -0.335 -0.321  0.156          
prtlts_Prtl -0.139  0.033 -0.395 -0.432  0.005 -0.095  0.565   
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.18052 (tol = 0.002, component 1)

Warning message:
In abbreviate(rn, minlength = 6) : abbreviate不适用于非ASCII字元
> lra <- read.csv(file.choose())
> m2 = glmer(object_case ~ number + animacy + order + tense + resultativity + 
+              boundedness + (1|verb_lemma), data = lra, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
Warning message:
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.26418 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
> summary(m2)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: object_case ~ number + animacy + order + tense + resultativity +      boundedness + (1 | verb_lemma)
   Data: lra

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   148.4    183.0    -65.2    130.4      336 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.73592  0.00000  0.00005  0.00844  0.77798 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 verb_lemma (Intercept) 221.6    14.89   
Number of obs: 345, groups:  verb_lemma, 171

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      -26.1970     9.7317  -2.692   0.0071 ** 
numbersingular     1.1154     1.3319   0.837   0.4023    
animacyeluta      -2.6822     5.0778  -0.528   0.5973    
animacyinimene    -5.0652     5.4291  -0.933   0.3508    
orderVO           -0.8986     1.5268  -0.589   0.5562    
tensepresent      -0.2413     1.4865  -0.162   0.8710    
resultativityyes  22.8050     5.0525   4.514 6.37e-06 ***
boundednessyes    15.6020     2.6845   5.812 6.18e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) nmbrsn anmcyl anmcyn ordrVO tnsprs rslttv
numbersnglr -0.105                                          
animacyelut -0.791 -0.072                                   
animacyinmn -0.739 -0.022  0.947                            
orderVO     -0.111 -0.121  0.057  0.068                     
tensepresnt -0.331  0.134  0.262  0.304  0.043              
reslttvtyys -0.872  0.148  0.459  0.402 -0.094  0.253       
bounddnssys -0.568 -0.037  0.114  0.023  0.127 -0.034  0.651
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.26418 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

My main questions are

1. what the warning message means

```
In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 1.26418 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

2. Could I get rid of this warning message and does the summary have any meaning if I got this error?
   Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you googled yet? https://www.google.com/search?q=Model+failed+to+converge+with+max|grad|  ; https://rdrr.io/cran/lme4/man/troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 1):

This is probably more of a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question, but the problem here is almost certainly the very low prevalence of nominative (1-outcome) results in your baseline levels, as indicated by the intercept estimate of -16 in one model and -26 in the other, and the correspondingly large values for some of your other parameters.  This is most likely a case of *(quasi) complete separation*, which you can read about CrossValidated or elsewhere.  In general, parameter estimates with absolute value >10 in a logistic regression are a red flag for this phenomenon (provided that your predictor variables are categorical or reasonably scaled numerical variables).

- The general conclusions of the model are *probably* OK.
- You can get more reliable p-values/CIs by likelihood ratio tests or profile confidence intervals
- For what it's worth, running the same model in `glmmTMB` and using the `diagnose()` function would probably have given you a similar answer.
- as indicated in `?lme4::troubleshooting` and elsewhere on the web, the brute-force check on whether you should be concerned about convergence warnings is to use `allFit()` and see whether the results using a variety of different optimizer are sufficiently similar for your purposes.